# Different tabBaritems for each view

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

i want different tabBaritems in each of my view currently didnt have any idea from where to start can any one give me the guideline so that i can get started on that plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you dont plan to insert any navigation controller, then u can start by choosing the tabbar controller template.

For more info you can try these tabbar tutorial.. Its quite detailed..

http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-tabbar-uitabbarcontroller-tutorial/

or if you want the tab bar with navigation contoller, try this tutorial

http://21gingerman.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/tutorial-and-sample-code-for-iphone-app-with-tab-bar-and-nav-bar/